# Qiskit Portfolio Optimization : Does the resulting matrix show the stock combination to select?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, vqe, optimization

The IBM Qiskit [Portfolio Optimization](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/finance/01_portfolio_optimization.html) sample finally provides an array similar to `[1,0,1,1]` representing the 4 digits as the stocks. So does the `0` and `1` represent the corresponding stock and whether to invest it or not ?

Is there any possibility to get in a weighted form such as invest 10% in stock #1 and 30% in stock #2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The problem has been formulated as a ***binary optimization*** problem.

As mentioned in the notebook, $x$ denotes the vector of ***binary*** decision variables, which indicates which assets to pick $x[i]=1$ and which not to pick $x[i]=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. Is there anyway that we could develop the solution that it gives a weight saying what percentage that each should be invested?